# Interpreting an interaction term

Tags: regression, interaction

I'm trying to interpret this interaction term etaerrorxlate

So eta_error is how many minute we were off in predicting the estimate time of delivery for the item (in minutes). This term can be positive or negative (if it's early, it will be negative, if the order is late, it will be positive)

Late indicator is a dummy saying  if the order was late or not

ETAerrorxLate is an interaction term, the late indicator times the ETA error.

The independant varialbe is "care cost per order" aka how much we spend on making the customer happy if their order is late (in dollars)

I am assuming that whehter the item is early or late, has an effect on the independant variable. Late orders should have a bigger effect on the care cost per order"

So my question is, how do i interpret these coefficents?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is "what is the intpretation of these coefficients?"

Comment: Please be more specific about what kind of interpretation you want, because we already have over [a thousand posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret*+regression+interaction) on "interpreting regression interactions".

Comment: Yes I am having trouble finding the exact post that could correspond. Because Late_Ind is a dummy variable, and then etaerrorxlate is an interaction term. So i'm looking on how to interpret all of these coefficients, but because i have an interaction and a dummy, i'm not sure how to do it

Comment: And if you need any more reference: I am adding the interaction term because This will allow the impact of an extra minute to be different if the order is on-time/early vs if the order is late. But I'm just not sure how to now interpret this term

Comment: Can you add the model specification? Or at least give us more info about the model?

Comment: @dimitriy of course. 
So my dependant variable is "care cost per order". So every order we send out has a "care cost" associated with it. The lowest it can be is zero. The care cost is a monetary value that goes up if the customer has stuff wrong with the order(so basically, a refund). We've found that late orders cost us the most, and we want to know how much. So My independant variable is "ETAerror". This is the difference bewteen the ETA we gave the customer for the order, and when it actually arrives. So an ETA error of 5 means the order was late by 5 minutes. continued in next comment...

Comment: So because I am assuming that late orders (or ETA erors that are positive numbers) have a bigger effect on Care Cost Per Order, I added a late_indicator dummy (1 if the order was late, 0 if not). And then an interaction term ETAerrorTIMESLate_Ind).

Comment: I forgot to say that if an ETA is early, the ETA_error would be negative, so -1 for one minute early, -2 for 2 minutes early, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interaction terms are tricky! One thing that is tricky about them is that including an interaction term changes the interpretation of the MAIN effect coefficients as well: specifically they coefficients for the other variables now tell you the effect for the variable in question when the other variable it's interacted with is ZERO, regardless of whether "zero" is a meaningful value.

Here's how to interpret all three coefficients in your model.

I'm assuming that  you mean your DEPENDENT (outcome) variable is cost per order

The late coefficient tells you how much the cost increases when the order is late and the estimated time is exactly right (error=0).

The eta_error coefficient tells you how much cost increases when the estimated time of delivery is one minute late and the order is NOT late (late=0).

The interaction term tells you how much more or less the effect of a late estimated time impacts cost when the order IS late.

So the model estimates that, for a non-late order, each minute late predicting the delivery adds .001 dollars to cost (which is not significantly different from zero). But if the order IS late then each minute actually costs less .06 dollars less than that...which means that when the order is late being late predicting delivery time can actually save money. Not sure if that makes sense or not but that's what the model says.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is super helpful. It does make sense that predicting that it can be late will save money. Because people get a bit more upset when they are told the order will be on time, but its late. So if we tell them it will be late, and it is, they are not as upset. At least it makese sense in my head haha

Answer (score 0):

With dummy variables set to `0` or `1` your full model

```
care_cost_per_order = b0 + b1*eta_error + b2*late_ind + b3*eta_error*late_ind
```

changes as follows:

```
late_ind = 0:

care_cost_per_order = b0 + b1*eta_error

# The coefficients vanish where `late_ind = 0`
```

```
late_ind = 1:

care_cost_per_order = b0 + b1*eta_error + b2*1 + b3*eta_error*1 
            = (b0 + b2) + (b1 + b3)*eta_error

# The coefficients are distributed between slope and intercept
# intercept = (b0 + b2)
# slope =  (b1 + b3)*eta_error`
```

Each model gives you specific information about `care_cost_per_order` when the order is late or not late. There is no need to estate the interaction variable as it will vanish if it is zero,or will be included in the calculation of the slope and intercept.

Comment: Thank you so much!